# How to avoid cookies popups in requests python?

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I was trying to post some data on website, but it didn't make post-request.

Then, I added ".text" to see the page html-code and it returned  the page's code with popup window.
Is it possible to bypass the popup window?

```
import requests 

print((requests.post("someurlhere", data={}).text)
```

[cookie popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJZiE.png)

Comment: can you share the URL if it's public